# Groupby and Sum function showing the index and sum of the non grouped items

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sum

I am working with an NHL data set and I am trying to calculate the sum of the pacific teams goals against my home team (Oilers). I want to remove the first index [0] that shows the sum of the goals against from the non pacific division teams efficiently. Is there an easier way?

My code is the following:

```
df.groupby('pacific_teams')['goals_against'].sum()
```

The results show:

```
pacific_teams

0            6.0   ***<----Remove this***

Anaheim      5.0

Calgary      2.0

LA           0.0

San Jose     0.0

Seattle      0.0

Vancouver    2.0

Vegas        3.0



pacific_conditions = [
    (df['Opponent'] == 'VAN'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'CGY'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'ANA'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'SEA'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'SJS'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'LAK'),
    (df['Opponent'] == 'VGK')
]
pacific_teams= ['Vancouver', 'Calgary', 'Anaheim', 'Seattle', 'San Jose', 'LA', 'Vegas']

df['PAC'] = np.select(pacific_conditions, pacific_teams)
df.loc[df['PAC']!=0].groupby('PAC')['Goals_Against'].sum()


df.head()
   Game        Date Opponent  EDM_Home  ... SHGF  SHGA  Blocked_Shots    Goalie
0     1  10/13/2021      VAN      True  ...  0.0   0.0           17.0     Smith
1     2  10/16/2021      CGY      True  ...  0.0   0.0           13.0     Smith
2     3  10/19/2021      ANA      True  ...  0.0   0.0           17.0  Koskinen
3     4  10/21/2021      ARI     False  ...  1.0   0.0           10.0  Koskinen
4     5  10/22/2021      VGK     False  ...  0.0   0.0           16.0  Koskinen
[5 rows x 23 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

team name in pacific_teams or PAC is a string. so to exclude use '0' and not just 0.

```
df.loc[df['pacific_teams']!='0'].groupby('Goals_Against')['goals_against'].sum()

df.loc[df['PAC']!='0'].groupby('PAC')['Goals_Against'].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried this, I still get that top line of 0 showing. I think the GroupBy function is grouping all the pacific teams together, but any other team that's not in that list is the index group of [0] and 6 is the sum of all their goals so far this season. The !=0 seemed to not change anything unfortunately...

Comment: can you add a few rows of the dataframe? ideally i'd need to see what values are in the 'pacific_teams' column as that's what you are grouping by.

Comment: So to simplify it, I have a column that has opponents in it and a column that has the goals that they have scored on us. I am trying to group the pacific teams in the opponent column (there are 7/30 values in that column that are pacific teams), and I want the total the sum for each pacific team.  I will post my code below since there is not enough space.

Comment: I put the code in the initial problem!

Comment: try not to simplify, as what you've provided isn't your dataframe and I'm still unable to tell what you're really doing. you should be able to use df.head() and paste that in. thanks. however, if it's alway the first row and you want to drop it, see this https://thispointer.com/drop-first-row-of-pandas-dataframe-3-ways/

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far Jonathan! I included the df head into the original post, (the goals against column is not visible but you can see the opponents and how they are grouped. Your link was helpful, so I appreciate it. Removing it that way will have to do for now.

Comment: turns out the zero is a string, not a number. this filters correctly df.loc[df['PAC']!='0'].groupby('PAC')['Goals_Against'].sum()  see quotes around the 0

Comment: This makes sense now, I must have missed that earlier on. So important with the quotes, thank you very much!